# dynamic URL with special characters redirecting me to a 404 page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, deployment, special-characters, urlencode

I have a webform application that when you login takes me to the homepage of my MVC application. In the process of logging in, I am forming a url that takes me to my MVC app. In this URL I am attaching an encrypted User ID. The problem is when this encrypted User Id contains special character such as "+" or "/". It messes up the and takes me to a 404 page. If there are no special characters then it works fine and takes me to the right page.

This how I form the URL

```
 Response.Redirect("http://mysite/UserRedirect/" + encryptedUserId)
```

MVC method

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult UserRedirect(string id = "")
 {
   //Decrypts UserID, then takes you to the homepage         
     return("Index");
 }
```

If the encryptedUserId contains special characters like the example below it messes up.

```
7hnQ+Nc= -> http://mysite/UserRedirect/7hnQ+Nc= ("+" sign)
```

or

```
 E/VDb7l= -> http://mysite/UserRedirect/E/VDb71 ("/" sign)
```

Otherwise if there are no special characters like below, then it works fine

```
NIatmgg= -> http://mysite/UserRedirect/NIatmgg=
```

This issue is occuring when the app is deployed on the server. How should I approach this?

When there is a "/" it's not even getting to my UserRedirect method.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

turns out you need to form the url with a "?=" instead of a slash "/". This now works. Thanks

Comment: although the 404 error is gone, but the parameter is not passed to controller

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure to encode (via UrlEncode) the encryptedUserId variable before the redirect call and decode (via UrlDecode) the id variable in the UserRedirect action?